# my UI goes disturbed when i use <?php echo form_open();?> in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, web

my web page design remains normal until i write

> once i use it, the content portion of the web just disturb code is given below

```
        <?php echo form_open('regform/register');?>
            <div class="first">
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="name"><strong>Name:<br /></strong> </label><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="55" id="name" class="inputtext" />
                    <label for="email"><strong>Email:<br /></strong></label><input type="text" name="email" maxlength="55" id="email" class="inputtext" />
                    <label for="password"><strong>Password:<br /></strong></label><input type="text" name="password" maxlength="55" id="password" class="inputtext" />
                    <label for="confirmpass"><strong>Confirm Password:<br /></strong></label><input type="text" name="confirm" maxlength="55" id="confirmpass" class="inputtext" />
                    <div>
                        <label for="newsletter"><input type="checkbox" id="newsletter" /><span>Subscribe to newsletter</span></label> 
                        <label class="terms" for="terms"><input type="checkbox" id="terms" /><span>I agree to the Terms and Conditions</span></label>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="completename"><strong>Complete name:</strong></label><input type="text" maxlength="55" id="completename" class="inputtext" />
                    <label for="address"><strong>Primary address:</strong></label><input type="text" maxlength="55" id="address" class="inputtext" />
                    <label for="billing"><strong>Billing address:</strong></label><input type="text" maxlength="55" id="billing" class="inputtext" />
                    <label for="city"><strong>City:</strong></label><label class="zipcode" for="zipcode"><strong>Zip Code:</strong></label>
                    <input type="text" maxlength="30" id="city" /> 
                    <input type="text" maxlength="30" id="zipcode" class="zipcode" />
                    <div>
                        <label for="shipping"><input type="checkbox" id="shipping" /><span> Same Shipping and Billing address</span></label> 
                        <label class="saveas" for="saveas"><input type="checkbox" id="saveas" /><span> Save as default address</span></label>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="" id="createaccount" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

this is how it looks after using "php echo form_open"

[image]

this is .css file for that portion

```
content div form div {  
background: url(../images/bg-form.jpg) no-repeat;  
float: left;  
height: 396px;  
margin: 0 0 0 24px;  
padding: 0;  
width: 463px;  
}  
#content div form div.first {  
margin-left: 0;  
}  
#content div form div fieldset {  
border: 0;  
margin: 20px auto;  
width: 386px;  
}  
#content div form div fieldset input.inputtext {  
background: url(../images/sprites-inputs.gif) no-repeat 0 -42px;  
border: 0;  
height: 31px;  
margin: 10px 0;  
padding: 0 5px;  
width: 376px;  
}  
#content div form div fieldset input#city {  
background: url(../images/sprites-inputs.gif) no-repeat 0 0;  
border: 0;  
height: 32px;  
margin: 10px 0;  
padding: 0 5px;  
width: 172px;  
}  
#content div form div fieldset label.zipcode {  
margin-left: 168px;  
}  
#content div form div fieldset input#zipcode {  
background: url(../images/sprites-inputs.gif) no-repeat 0 0;  
border: 0;  
height: 32px;  
margin: 0 0 0 15px;  
padding: 0 5px;  
width: 172px;  
}  
#content div form div div {  
background: none;  
float: none;  
height: auto;  
margin-left: 0;  
margin-top: 33px;  
width: auto;  
}
```

Comment: `form_close()` missing ?

Comment: problem remains same unfortunately

Comment: You have a trailing </div> after the closing </form> tag. Delete the trailing div and then you should be good.

Comment: no change problem remain same , this change disturb UI even more

Comment: Have you validated the entire HTML file with w3c schools markup validator?

Comment: no i am using codeigniter validator using : helper['form','url'] in controller and also validatins takes place in controller

Comment: it's very hard to guess what you want to achieve showing only a bunch of code and an image how it should **not look like**. create a http://jsfiddle.net or similar example and add it to your question. Your `css` is wrong,and there is no #content, so I'd start working from there.

Comment: #content is in the header file and its tags closes in footer. css is perfect and working greatout with "<?php echo form_open();?>"

Answer (score 0):

i think You have missed classes for the form element

just use it like

```
echo form_open('your_url', array(
    'class' => 'your classes', 
    'role' => 'role of form'
));
```

Comment: it still remains same, no change in the UI